# PowerShell ISE and PowerShell.Exiting event

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm using the PowerShell.Exiting engine event to save my command history and do some other tidying up when I close a PowerShell session, registering it in my profile thus:

```
# Set up automatic functionality on engine exit.
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action `
{
    #stuff
    ...
}
```

This works perfectly when I use PowerShell in a console window, but when I'm running PowerShell in ISE, it appears that the PowerShell.Exiting event somehow never fires, since nothing I put in there, be it the usual stuff or test code, ever runs.

Is this a known problem, and if so, is there a known workaround or alternative?

Comment: Just to clarify: did you add the code in your ISE profile? Remember that ISE has a seperate profile ("Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1")

Comment: How are you closing ISE? You need to type exit at the console or use Alt+F4. The following works for me when I use the proper exit method.

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    Start-Process "Notepad.exe"
}

Comment: Yes - well, I have it in the CurrentUserAllHosts profile, profile.ps1.  And there's enough other stuff in there that I can be sure the code around it's all executing.  get-job also shows it registered.

Comment: I put your code with a simple `Set-Content -Value "Hi" -Path C:\test.txt` action in my PowerShellISE profile, and it executed fine when I closed ISE(PS3.0) normally.

Comment: @ravikanth - exit, at the console.  I also just tried your example, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have tested this in v3 ISE. what version are you using?

Comment: 3.0, as shipped with Windows 8.

Comment: hmm, interesting. May be something wrong with profile? try running PowerShell_ise.exe -noprofile and then try this.

Comment: That worked. Hm.  Guess I'll cut down the profile to just the register-engineevent and start putting stuff back until it breaks.

Comment: I can't get this to work in ISE at all either. Launching ISE with -noprofile and manually pasting in my 'Register-EngineEvent' block, doesn't execute when I type exit at the command line within ISE. Using PS5 on W10.

Comment: `Start-Process "Notepad.exe"` didn't work, but `Start-Process "Notepad.exe" | out-null` did. This was launching ISE as normal, without -noprofile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is weird as hell.

After cutting down the profile completely outside the Register-EngineEvent call only to find that it still didn't work, I started to cut down the contents of that, too, and restored the rest of the profile to its original state.  Here are my findings:

If you have a `write-host`, or other output to the PowerShell host, in the scriptblock for `Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exited`, it doesn't run when you exit ISE (even though it works fine when you exit the console).

In fact, *none* of the scriptblocks you have registered against the PowerShell.Exited event appear to run, even ones that don't contain any statements outputting to the host.  (Which is why when I tested other people's working examples up above, they didn't work for me unless I started PowerShell without running the profile that added the existing event handler.)

Expunge all statements that cause host output from the scriptblocks you use with `Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exited` , or redirect the output somewhere else, and they all start working.

(Take this with appropriate quantities of salt, since I have not yet had time to go chasing it with a debugger, but I have a sneaking suspicion ISE is closing down its tab before the engine is done with it...)

Comment: Thanks - this helped. Piping to out-null seemed to work for me for starting notepad. I was hoping that I could use this method to save the current open ISE tabs ($psISE.PowerShellTabs.Files.FullPath) to a file upon ISE exit, but rather than writing the values, it blanked the file. I suspected that $psISE was empty by this point, but I couldn't even `Write-Output` to Out-File either.

Comment: I was able to write content to a text file using `add-content` (or `set-content`) but sadly, any reference to $psISE was empty.