# How to get an Unix like atexit in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

When creating an OLE object it is necessary to release it at the end of the program. Otherwise the process keeps running in the background.

I wrote the following example:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# some long running code here

finally
{
  "running finally"
  [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
}
```

When I stop the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> during the "long running code" in the middle the finally block does not get executed. Whenever I do it I get just another `EXCEL.EXE` process in the process table.

How can I reliably release the COM object even if the user interrupts the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: Is the first bit at least in a `try` block?

Comment: @arco444 It does not make any difference if it is or not.

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fb409048-a607-4895-8ab3-08c2ec656c7a/trapping-ctrlc-in-powershell-v2?forum=winserverpowershell) - the second answer looks like it could fit your scenario

Comment: @arco444 That looks as if I have to write some kind of cooperative multitasking from scratch just to get an exit handler.

Comment: Well you're going to need at least two threads whatever. If you're doing a bunch of processing in your main prog, you need another thread to trap some sort of interrupt and signal the main thread. Using jobs would be the way to do this in Powershell. `Get-Help about_jobs`

Answer (score 0):

Try [Engine Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604596/powershell-ise-and-powershell-exiting-event) (works only in console, not Powershell ISE):

```powershell
# Set up automatic functionality on engine exit.
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
}
```