# Run script on powershell exit

Tags: windows, powershell

How would I run a powershell script that would run on either, the `exit` command, or the shell closing. I would want this script to run on every shell close not just for one shell.

[Script](http://poshcode.org/5289)

Comment: Check this question [How to get an Unix like atexit in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090924/how-to-get-an-unix-like-atexit-in-powershell) Although to make this run at *every* shell, you need it to include the script listed in the answer, probably by auto-importing a module. I doubt that this functionality is not considered a security violation.

Comment: Downvote for the dead link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it out of the function and run it in the scriptblock, like this:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action {

$foo = @"
 .d8888b.  8888888888 8888888888      Y88b   d88P  .d88888b.  888     888
d88P  Y88b 888        888              Y88b d88P  d88P" "Y88b 888     888
 "Y888b.   8888888    8888888            Y888P    888     888 888     888
    "Y88b. 888        888                 888     888     888 888     888
      "888 888        888                 888     888     888 888     888
Y88b  d88P 888        888                 888     Y88b.  d88P Y88b. .d88P
 "Y8888P"  8888888888 8888888888          888      "Y88888P"   "Y88888P"
 .d8888b.  8888888b.     d8888  .d8888b.  8888888888
d88p  Y88b 888   Y88b   d88888 d88P  Y88b 888
 "Y888b.   888   d88P d88P 888 888        8888888
    "Y88b. 8888888P" d88P  888 888        888
      "888 888      d88P   888 888    888 888
Y88b  d88P 888     d8888888888 Y88b  d88P 888
 "Y8888P"  888    d88P     888  "Y8888P"  8888888888
 .d8888b.   .d88888b.  888       888 888888b.    .d88888b. Y88b   d88P
d88P  Y88b d88P" "Y88b 888   o   888 888  "88b  d88P" "Y88b Y88b d88P
888        888     888 888 d888b 888 8888888K.  888     888   Y888P
888        888     888 8888888888888 888  "Y88b 888     888    888
888    888 888     888 88888P Y88888 888    888 888     888    888
Y88b  d88P Y88b. .d88P 8888P   Y8888 888   d88P Y88b. .d88P    888
 "Y8888P"   "Y88888P"  888P     Y888 8888888P"   "Y88888P"     888
"@
 $file="c:\.seeyouspacecowboy"
 $foo | out-file $file
 $colour=("red","yellow","darkyellow","green","cyan","darkcyan","darkmagenta")
 [int]$num=-1
 $info = (get-content $file)
 Write-Host ""
 foreach($i in $info) 
    {
     [int]$perspective=($num / 3)
     write-host $i -foregroundcolor $colour[$perspective]
     $num++   
    }
 Write-Host ""

 }
```

*of course, make sure you are with admin privilege as it write to c:\

Comment: Nope, still getting errors. `Unexpected token 'Y88b.' in expression or statement.
At C:\Dev\spacecowboy.ps1:7 char:11` also please delete this question, and edit it into your other question.

Comment: for the test, don't run it as a ps1 file, just start powershell as administrator and paste the code, type exit, and check the c drive, i test this with PS2 and 3 works great

Comment: This doesn't work. There is no errors, or output. On top this this wouldn't be suitable if I had to paste the code in everytime I started the powershell.

Comment: of course not, but just for the test, do you see message that the event registerd? do you run powershell as admin?
also, you can add this to powershell profile so it will run automatically on every powershell start

Comment: I do not see the event as registered. I am running as Admin.

Comment: then you must missing something, copy paste your complete code or run it on another to computer to test it, it sure works...

Comment: I got it work. You forgot to mention you have to leave a trailing line for Powershell to interpret as a command.

Comment: The idea is good, thanks, but most of your solution is just noise, and might mislead people into thinking that the problem is more complicated than it really is.  I prefer Avshalom's solution.

Comment: hey @Avshalom , does `.d8888b.` means something ?

Answer (score 10):

Using [Register-EngineEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-engineevent?view=powershell-7) you can do this:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action { 'Type your Code' }

# Alternatively with hiding the event: 
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent –Action { yourExitFunction; }
```

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? When entered I receive the following error. `Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting â€ <<<< “Action {
is missing the terminator: ".`

Comment: Sure, ran this now on PS v2 and v3, works fine:

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { New-Item c:\Test.txt -Type File }
show the command you ran and the error

Comment: I have no errors now, but nothing is happening on exit.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is a [try-finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6) block, which will execute the finally block on error or ctrl-c:

```
try {
    # Main code
} finally {
    # Code to run on exit
}
```

Comment: Tested on PowerShell 7.0.0, finally block does not run.