# Actions on powershell window closing with 'x'

Tags: powershell

There is at least [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116756/run-script-on-powershell-exit) on how to initiate actions on shell closing. The problem is it doesn't catch closing powershell window with 'x' button. Apparently it doesn't generate said event. Is there any way to capture such close and force actions upon it?

What I want is to pipe some values upon closing from session variables (hashtable of `System.Diagnostisc.Process`) to system variables upon closing. So that new session can access them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the expression "Every problem can be solved with another level of indirection" [(see also)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection) applies here.

May really depend on your needs, and how your script(s) work, etc.  Perhaps you could start each of your scripts that need this behavior by loading some common library, which exports a function that watches for the exit of a given PowerShell process, namely your current one.

You can get this info using the `$pid` variable and pass that to your watcher function which launches a process to wait for the exit of your current script. This could be another script, C#, etc.  See also `Get-Process -Id $pid`.

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish it is hard to recommend anything more specific that might meet your needs such as logging, transcripts, user education, detection of 'dirty shutdowns' of your code, etc.

Comment: Loading a DLL should be sufficient, as those are notified of impending doo–erm, process shutdown.

Comment: @Kory Gill I updated question with my needs - want to save a hashtable of active processes for future sessions.

Comment: @Joey could you please elaborate about DLL, at least where to look for?