# Command that opens exe file in powershell, then closes powershell when exe is closed and runs command?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I know how to already run an exe file, easy part.
I also figured out how to run a command when powershell closes:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action { 'Code' }
```

But I can't figure out how I would run a program with Powershell and then have it execute a command in Powershell when it closes, and then close Powershell itself.

```
$job = Start-Job { net start wuauserv }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\CpuCoreParking\CpuCoreParking3.exe" -Wait

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action {
$job = Start-Job { net stop wuauserv }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
```

This is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to stop the service on the end. Nothing happens, it just closes itself after I close the program. It does do something but ... not sure what.

Comment: the `Start-Process` cmdlet has a `-Wait` parameter that may give you all that you need for this. have you tried it? [*grin*]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116756/run-script-on-powershell-exit

Comment: Not a duplicate. I know how to run a command on exit. I was asking how to make the Powershell wait for a program run within it to close, before it closes itself automatically together with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problems:

First of all

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action {}
```

Makes the Powershell itself wait to be closed. So if it closes by the means of it finishing the execution of all commands, it will not run the command.

Second

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c net stop wuauserv"
```

This needs administrator privileges. So it's best you turn this into an exe files with admin privileges. That's the one method that comes to mind. Here is the finished code that functions as it should:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c net start wuauserv"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting –Action {
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c net stop wuauserv"
}
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\CpuCoreParking\CpuCoreParking3.exe" -Wait
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c net stop wuauserv"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
```

Or you can replace the Invoke-Expression commands with

```
$job = Start-Job { net start/stop wuauserv }
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Which I believe doesn't require admin privileges.